# get column names from variables sqlite python3 sqlalchemy

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

I want to store the details stored in `x` variable to the sqlite database using flask sqlalchemy. How to make it possible.

Here's the code i wrote:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_httpauth import HTTPBasicAuth
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:////tmp/u.db'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model) :
    x = ['username = "sam"', 'password = "sam123"']
    u1 = (x[0].split()[0])
    p1 = (x[1].split()[0])
    print(u1,p1)
    __tablename__ = 'users'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    u1 = db.Column(db.String(32), index = True)
    p1 = db.Column(db.String(128))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    db.create_all()
    print("db created")
    app.run(host='0.0.0.0', port=5001)
```

table created in sqlite:

```
id   u1  p1
```

Required table to be created in sqlite and data to be loaded:

```
id username password
1  sam      sam123
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your table needs to define the columns with the names that you want:

```
class User(db.Model) :

    __tablename__ = 'users'

    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key = True)
    username = db.Column(db.String(32), index = True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(128))
```

You can make function to extract the username and password from `x`:

```
def get_user_data(data):
    user_data = []
    for item in data:
        part = item.partition(' = ')[2]
        cleaned = part.replace('"', '')
        user_data.append(cleaned)
    return user_data
```

And create a `User` instance like this:

```
username, password = get_user_data(x)
user = User(username=username, password=password)
```